# Socket io seems to keep reverting to pollin

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to setup a socket io server using websockets with node and react.

Atm I have this on the server side:

```
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    io.emit('chat message', {
      ...msg,
      _id: Math.random(),
      createdAt: new Date(),
    });
  });
});
```

And this on the frontend:

```
  const socket = useRef(io('http://localhost:3000'));
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current.on('chat message', function (msg) {
      setMessages([...messages, msg]);
    });
  }, [messages]);

  return(
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          socket.current.emit('chat message', {
            text: 'msg sent by ',
            createdBy: { name: user.name, image: user.profileImage },
          });
        }}
      >
        Click
      </Button>
  )
```

Now this 'works' however instead of using websockets it seems to be using polling as shown in the network log:
[image: Network log showing polling not websockets]

Would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: That's the default behavior of socket.io. Don't worry.

Comment: @code Does this mean it's using websockets? Seems odd it would need to send so many xhr requests for websockets.

Comment: It sends several xhr requests to start and if both sides agree, then it switches to webSocket. That is the default behavior.  It is possible to specify a client option when you connect that immediately starts with a webSocket.  Keep in mind that all webSocket connections start with one http request.

Comment: jfriend00 has the right answer.